# slf4j/logback/jcl-over-slf4j - still routing to logback even if jcl-over-slf4j is not in dependencies?

Tags: java, spring, maven, slf4j, apache-commons-logging

While experimenting with logging dependencies, I had the following situation:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>version99</id>
        <url>http://version99.qos.ch/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>99-empty</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.25</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--<dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.25</version>
    </dependency>-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

It is important to note that the dependency to `jcl-over-slf4j` is commented out. To my surprise, the logs from Spring were still processed by Logback. How is this possible? There is no bridge active between jcl and slf4j, so how can we end up in Logback?

I verified that:

- Only `commons-logging-99-empty.jar` is in classpath.
- No `jcl-over-slf4j` is mentioned in `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=org.slf4j`

I am really confused. I expected `NoClassDefFoundError`'s on classes from `commons-logging`.

Please note that I have no intentions to leave that dependency to `jcl-over-slf4j` in comments. I just want to understand what is going on. I thought I finally understood these logging dependencies, but apparently, in practice, it is behaving totally different that I expected.

Comment: Logging in Java = PITA. Just kidding, it's lovely.

Answer (score 10):

Are you using Spring 5?

In Spring 5, there is another so-called bridge introduced: `spring-jcl`. See https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-14512 for development notes.

So in your case, while `jcl-over-slf4j` was no longer in the classpath, `spring-jcl` still is and it is doing **exactly the same thing** (and a bit more, as it also routes `commons-logging` to `log4j` or `java.util.logging` depending on what is on your classpath) as `jcl-over-slf4j`.

If you have both `jcl-over-slf4j` and `spring-jcl`, it is basically undefined who wins. That's okay, since they both do the same thing. However, you have overlapping classes, so this might bite you somewhere else.

This is logging terror at it's finest.